# The state is not updated via the useState hook the first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The state is updated only on the next keystroke but with the previous state. Screen 1

When you click on updateForm (), it is also empty, only after the second click, the state is updated. Screen 2

I understand that this is due to asynchrony, but in this case I do not know how to use it.

### Home.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Form } from '../components/Form/Form';

const Home = () => {
  const [dateForm, setDataForm] = useState({});

  const updateForm = eachEnry => {
    setDataForm(eachEnry);
    console.log(dateForm);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Form updateForm={updateForm} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default Home;
```

### Form.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './Form.scss';

export const Form = ({ updateForm }) => {
  const initInputState = {
    name: '',
    password: ''
  };
  const [dataForm, setDataForm] = useState(initInputState);
  const { name, password } = dataForm;

  const onChange = e => {
    setDataForm({
      ...dataForm,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  const onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    updateForm(dataForm);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name"
          value={name}
          onChange={onChange}
          name="name"
        />
        <input
          placeholder="Password"
          onChange={onChange}
          value={password}
          type="text"
          name="password"
        />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Ввод инпута]
[image: получаю данные формы в родительском компоненте]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your code is working fine.** You just doing *console.log* before the state is updated. State updates happen not when you using an update state function. It's happening when all component action and nested components actions are done.

**Check your code with console log on another place [click to check](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-silence-q0hgq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FHome.jsx&theme=dark)**

As you can see I placed a *console log* on every *Home* component rerender. You can check that all works fine.

*P.S. I did some improvements to your code. Check if u like it. And add a comment to updateForm function. Check this one too, please.*

Answer (score 0):

You evidently are not setting your state properly, here

```
   setDataForm({
      ...dataForm,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
```

should be

```
 setDataForm(c => ({
     ...c,
     [e.target.name]: e.target.value
 }));
```

Comment: @TosinFelixsonYusuf nothing changed(

Comment: Are you checking here 
```
  const updateForm = eachEnry => {
    setDataForm(eachEnry);
    console.log(dateForm);
  };
```
To see if state is updated? then it is wrong because set state is asynchronous, and by the time that line is evaluated it is getting old and stale data, 
Perhaps you want to use a useEffect hook to check if indeed state is updated